# A probability density function with sharp turn at its mode $(f''(\text{mode})=-\infty)$

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions

Does there exist a known (with name) probability density function $f$ with mode $x_0$ where $f''(x_0)=-\infty$ and also one has

1. $f$ and $f'$ are both continuous (and hence $f'(x_0)$ exists and is equal to zero)
2. $f$ and $f''$ are symmetric around $x_0$

Preference is for a probability distribution with bounded support.

Update: To be more specific I'm trying to find a PDF which matches below graph (the graph is derived from a very complicated ODE and hence I should "guess" the solution). The ones with absolute values over 10 for mode are basically infinity.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).

Sometimes people call this the "double exponential distribution", but that term is also used for a distribution whose density is an iterated exponential distribution. I think I've also seen this called a bilateral exponential distribution.

The function $f,$ rather than being called a probability distribution, should be called a probability density function. But the expression $f(x) \, dx$ (with $\text{“}dx\text{''}$ may be called a probability distribution since it can be identified with the mapping
$$
A\mapsto \int_A f(x)\,dx
$$
for (Borel) sets $A.$ Thus you could say:

> Does there exist a known (with name) continuous  symmetric (around its mode $x_0$) probability distribution whose density function $f$ satisfies $f''(x_0)=\infty$?

If you want a bounded support, there is the triangular distribution
$$
f(x)\,dx= (1 - |x|)\,dx \quad \text{for } 0<x<2.
$$
This is the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables that are uniformly distributed in the interval $(0,1).$

Comment: I think in your examples $f'$ is not continuous, right? So you would want something more like $c_1 - c_2 |x|^{3/2}$ (but this wouldn't have a name).

Comment: @Ian : Yes. $\qquad$